# How do I set Hotkeys in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

I'm new to Flex and i want to bind STRG+I to trigger a function.
How do i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's different things. I haven't personally done it yet, so after checking some Adobe documentation here what I found.

One can use flash.ui.Keyboard class in order to have a full keyboard control for your application. That would mostly require AIR tho, since the hotkeys are quite limited inside a browser.

In the case you're not in AIR, but in the flash player sitting in the browser, you can do it using simple event handling. Here's some nice tutorial how to do it:
http://tutorials.flashmymind.com/2009/02/actionscript-3-keyboard-events/

Hope it helps!